# Wait for button click to continue the program

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I'm new to GUI in general. I wanted to make one, which ask a user for an input. This input should afterwards be further processed in an Object.

This is my `objectClass`.

```
public class AnObject {
        private String property;
        public AnObject(){}
        public String getProperty() {return property;}
        public void setProperty(String property) {this.property = property;}
}
```

My `MainClass` with main and `gui` method:

```
public class MainClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            AnObject anObject = new AnObject();
            gui(anObject);
            System.out.println(anObject.getProperty()); //always null
        }

        public static void gui(AnObject anObject){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            JButton button = new JButton("ok");
            JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
            panel.add(button);
            panel.add(textField);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    anObject.setProperty(textField.getText());
                    System.out.println(anObject.getProperty()); //Input
                    frame.dispose();
                }
            });
        }
}
```

My Output is always...

```
null
//input from gui
```

In this order. I guess I am too slow at the input, how can I get the program to wait for me?

Comment: There is no need for the last line in `main()`. The print out happens already when the action listener is called. The listener is also the place for further processing of input (or better calling a function to do that).

Comment: Make the `JFrame` a `JOptionPane` (or a modal dialog) instead. Then the code will wait until the dialog or option pane is dismissed.

Comment: See [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for examples of using a `JOptionPane`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the method wait - all methods return once finished.

This one (gui) will return once you set up the gui (that is add the button).

So add a

```
while(frame.isDisplayable()) try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) {}
```

at the end of the method. This way when the frame is disposed (after you enter the values and press the buton) the method will exit.

This way is however hazardous programming - holding up a method for no apparent reason.

But if it is what you want this is what you have to do.